# Не работает импорт стилей в React при интеграции в Angular приложение

Tags: reactjs, angular, импорт

Моя задача интегрировать React в Angular приложение. Для этого был создан компонент, который будет служить "мостом" между Angular и React:

```js
import { Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import { ReactRootComponent } from "./ReactRootComponent/ReactRootComponent";
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

@Component({
  selector: "app-integration",
  template: `<div #reactRoot></div>`,
})
export class IntegrationComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild("reactRoot", { read: ElementRef, static: true })
  ref: ElementRef;
  constructor() {}

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.renderComponent();
  }

  public ngOnChanges(): void {
    this.renderComponent();
  }

  private renderComponent() {
    ReactDOM.render(
      React.createElement(ReactRootComponent),
      this.ref.nativeElement
    );
  }
}
```

Сам же `ReactRootComponent` выглядит вот так:

```js
import React from "react";
import "./test.css";


export const ReactRootComponent: React.FC = () => {

  return (
    <div className="test">
     Hello world
    </div>
  );
};
```

Приложение работает, компонент React рендерится. Но проблема в том, что стили не применяются, `import "./test.css` не работает. Я пробовал и в качестве модуля импортировать этот файл стилей: `import styles from "./test.module.css"`. Здесь и вовсе ругается

> Не удается найти модуль "./test.module.css" или связанные с ним объявления типов

Как исправить неработающие импорты?

Comment: А ты уверен, что без ангуляра работает? По описанию кажется, что он не при делах.

Comment: @Qwertiy это мой первый опыт подобных интеграций. Когда мне нужно реакт приложение, я его создаю через create-react-app, и всё отлично работает. Тут же мне пришлось через npm устанавливать react и react-dom.

Comment: @Qwertiy Советовался с другими людьми, дошли к мнению что это вебпак не может собрать все эти импорты. Поэтому, я пробовал установить 
[css-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader)
[style-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader)
и модифицировал конфиг по [этим советам](https://dev-gang.ru/article/personaliziruite-svou-angular-sborku-s-pomosczu-webpack-tgr46ybetn/). В итоге, проект не запускается вовсе ибо ругается уже на некоторые ангуляровские импорты стилей. В таком случае возникает другой вопрос: как их "помирить" и заставить работать вместе?

Comment: @Qwertiy и на данный момент, пока проблема не решена, как альтернативу использую библиотеку styled-components

Comment: ?скомпилить реакт компонент как `customElements` чем-нибудь вроде `microbundle`

Comment: https://github.com/preactjs/preact-custom-element/issues/28

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смог откопать решение проблемы!

Для компонента-моста в декоратор `@Component` задаем следующие параметры: `styleUrl` с путем на нужный CSS/SCSS файл и `encapsulation` со значением `ViewEncapsulation.None`.

В общем итоге, всё должно выглядеть таким образом:

```js
@Component({
  selector: "app-integration",
  template: `<div #reactRoot></div>`,
  styleUrls: ["./test.scss"],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
```

В самом уже React компоненте импортируем указанный в `styleUrls` файл стилей:

```
import "./../test.scss";
```

Моя структура папок в проекте:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Правда, для меня в текущем проекте это уже не играет никакой роли, ибо львиная доля дизайна уже написана на styled-components